# How to write sign like that pic

Tags: symbols, draw

Please help me

How to write  sign like that pic

[image]

Comment: The line should be like a fraction line?

Comment: Is it like a $\div$ symbol but with two dots over and under the line? Or you mean something different?

Comment: -1: This is a very poor question as it provides no context (will this be used in a mathematical context, or as part of a diagram, say) and no indication of effort. Moreover, neither the title nor the question body suggests anything that this post will be helpful to future visitors.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX](//tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436). Questions about how to draw specific graphics that just post an image of the desired result are really not reasonable questions to ask on the site. Please post a minimal compilable document showing that you've tried to produce the image and then people will be happy to help you with any specific problems you may have.  See [minimal working example (MWE)](//tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) for what needs to go into such a document.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Like this?

[image]

This geometer symbol can be draw as small picture: `pic` and can be positioned anywhere on map's lines:

```
\documentclass[tikz, margin=3mm]{standalone}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[
          dot/.style = {circle, draw, semithick, fill=white, outer sep=2mm,
                        node contents={}},
pics/progress/.style = {code = {\node[dot,above left];
                                \node[dot,above right];
                                \node[dot,below left];
                                \node[dot,below right];}
                        }
                        ]
\draw[very thick] (0,0) -- ++ (2,0) pic [pos=0.6] {progress};
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you so much

Comment: @AltantsoojTseveenjav, you are welcome! Instead saying  "thank you " you could up-vote answer ;-)

Answer (score 10):

Here's a possibility. You should be more precise about what the symbol is used for.

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\newcommand{\fourcircles}{%
  \mathrel{%
    \tfrac{\,{\circ}\,{\circ}\,}{\raisebox{0.25\height}{$\scriptstyle{\circ}\,{\circ}$}}%
  }%
}

\begin{document}

$a\fourcircles b$

\end{document}
```

[image]

With smaller circles:

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\newcommand{\fourcircles}{%
  \mathrel{%
    \tfrac{\scriptscriptstyle\,{\circ}\,{\circ}\,}
          {\raisebox{0.75\height}{$\scriptscriptstyle{\circ}\,{\circ}$}}%
  }%
}

\begin{document}

$a\fourcircles b$

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: This symbol is used as marks on maps of some property border, probably meaning that it lay for example on middle of stone fence (which are usual in Italy, Dalmatia etc).

Answer (score 8):

I made it `\mathrel`, but that can be changed.  Automatically works across math styles.  Same height as `+` sign.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{scalerel,tabstackengine}
\newcommand\mysym{\mathrel{\scalerel*{\ensurestackMath{\setstackgap{S}{0pt}%
  \Shortstack{\circ\circ\\{-}\!\!{-}\!\!{-}\\\circ\circ}}}{+}}}
\begin{document}
$a\mysym b+c$

$\scriptstyle a\mysym b+c$

$\scriptscriptstyle a\mysym b+c$
\end{document}
```

[image]

Here's a version that better matches the rule thickness

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{scalerel,tabstackengine}
\newcommand\mysym{\mathrel{\scalerel*{\ensurestackMath{\setstackgap{S}{3pt}%
  \Shortstack{\circ\,\circ\\\rule[.5pt]{1.7em}{1pt}\\\circ\,\circ}}}{+}}}
\begin{document}
$a\mysym b+c$

$\scriptstyle a\mysym b+c$

$\scriptscriptstyle a\mysym b+c$
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 5):

Still another possible way to do it:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{boldline}
\usepackage{booktabs}

\newcommand{\Fourcircles}{%
  \mathrel{%
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{0.5}%\setlength{\jot}{0pt}
   \vcenter{\hbox{$\begin{array}{@{\mkern2mu}>{\scriptscriptstyle}c@{\mskip2mu}>{\scriptscriptstyle}c@{\mkern 2mu}}
          \circ & \circ\\
\noalign{\vskip-0.6pt}
\hlineB{1.2}
\noalign{\vskip-0.6pt}
          \circ & \circ
\end{array} $}}}%
}%

\begin{document}

$a \Fourcircles b$

\end{document}
```

[image]